After applying Gram Schmidt to orthonormalize columns that are random normal gaussian vectors what is the resulting distribution?
From reading through responses in these answers here and here, I know that if I have a gaussian random vector $X \sim \mbox{Norm}(0,1)$ that $X^2$ should have a Chi squared distribution.
I also think based on what I read here that if you take the product of two independent normal gaussian random vectors the result will still be a gaussian random vector, just unnormalized.
Edit: The product of two independent gaussians is actually not gaussian -- thank you to the person in the comments for that clarification).
(Please let me know if I have a misconception on the above.)
My main question is: if I have a matrix that I build iteratively, adding a new random normal vectors to it each iteration and then applying Gram Schmidt will I be able to say anything about the distribution of the resulting columns?
So to clarify the process is:

Take random normal vector.
Make this random vector a new column of the matrix, M.
Orthonormalize the columns of M via Gram Schmidt.

Can I know anything about the distributions of the columns of M?
In Gram Schmidt it looks like we are really multiplying two gaussian random vectors  $\langle v_i,v_j\rangle$. Then we take that product and multiply it by $v_j$. I'm not sure we can say this is independent of the previous product since $v_j$ is included in that product. So basically we take the product of two normal gaussian random variable and multiply it by a normal gaussian random vector? (This is also then subtracted from a normal gaussian) Can we say anything about the resulting columns of M? Would this end up being Chi squared since it sort of involves $v_j$ times $v_j$?
Any insight is greatly appreciated! I sometimes struggle with visualizing different distributions.

The product of two Gaussians is not Gaussian

@JoseAvilez okay thank you! I must've misinterpreted that. Is it also chi squared or is it something else?

Thinking about support before thinking about distributions on that space. What are the possibilities for M that you could get? Don't push forward to just a single column or single entry yet.

@AHusain The support for a gaussian is the set of all real numbers. So are when we multiply two or three things with support on all real numbers the support is still all real numbers? (unlike when we square one single one and we end up with just positive numbers like when we get chi squared?)

No, I meant about the entirety of M. If you just focus on the entries or just look at a single column of M, you have pushed forward along the map that forgets all the other entries. I am asking you to think about the space you have before you do that focusing. What subset of $R^{n^2}$ is it where M lives (being as specific as possible)?

@AHusain I honestly am not sure. I'm not sure how to narrow it down from all real numbers. Can you possibly please give me another hint?
